# Registry settings for autocomplete "default" options in IE8

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, windows-registry

I use autocomplete paswords for many sites, but every time I need to change from default option "No"
to "yes", because the default value of message:
"Do you want IE to remember this password"
is "NO" instead of "Yes".

Please tell me a registry entry where I can modify this value.

Answer (score 0):

I think:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\AutoComplete]
"AutoSuggest"="yes"
```

but not sure